# PHP conditional on query string with id

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
    if('open' == $post->comment_status || !isset($_GET['wp_accept_favor']))
    {

// show comment form

    }
else
{
    // dont show comment form
    }
```

domain.com/?wp_accept_favor then show comment form

domain.com/?wp_accept_favor=2 then dont show comment form

How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Now that you introduced the comment status (my answer came before your edit, now deleted), if comments aren't allowed then do you always have to do B?

Comment: Updated question to hopefully make sense. Basically I want to check if the query exists with a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if('open' == $post->comment_status || 
             (isset($_GET['wp_accept_favor']) && empty($_GET['wp_accept_favor'])) )
{

    // show comment form

}
else if(isset($_GET['wp_accept_favor']) && !empty($_GET['wp_accept_favor']))
{
    // do not show comment form 
}
```